# Date formatted with an RTL locale does not format correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, right-to-left

I have a date that is formatted with locale 'ar' and the page is flipped with `<body dir='rtl'>`
but then the date is messed up when it happens. How can that be fixed

```js
const options = { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' }

var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('ar', options)

// Use it.

document.getElementById('dateResult').innerHTML = date;
```

```html
<body dir='rtl'>
<p>
   dateResult: <span id="dateResult"></span>
</p>
</body>
```

I would expect answer to be
"FormattedDate in Arabic format :dateResult"

Comment: That is the exact same result one gets when the body _is not_ in RTL. What is your expected output?

Comment: What is the output you are expecting or require?

Comment: This is a Gregorian Date. Why do you want to format it in Arabic?

Comment: Use locale as `'ar-EG'` otherwise just use locale `en`